# What is `np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[np.float64]]` and why does `np.typing.NDArray[np.float64]` alias it?

Tags: python, numpy, typing

The [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html) for `np.typing.NDArray` says that it is "a generic version of `np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[+ScalarType]]`". Where is the generalization in "generic" happening?

And in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__class_getitem__.html) for `numpy.ndarray.__class_getitem__` we have this example `np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[Any]]` with no explanation as to what the two arguments are.

And why can I do `np.ndarray[float]`, ie just use one argument? What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Generic" in this context means ["generic type"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/#specification) (see also [the Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generic-type)), typing-related objects that can be subscripted to generate more specific type "instances" (apologies for the sloppy jargon, I'm not well-versed in typing talk). Think [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) that lets you use `List[int]` to denote a homogeneous list of ints.

[As of Python 3.9](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) most standard-library collections have been upgraded to be compatible with typing as generic types themselves. Since `tuple[foo]` used to be invalid until 3.9, it was safe to allow `tuple[int, int]` to mean the same thing that `typing.Tuple[int, int]` used to mean: a tuple of two integers.

So as of 3.9 NumPy also allows using the `np.ndarray` type as a generic, this is what `np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[Any]]` does. This "signature" matches the [actual signature of `np.ndarray.__init__()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) (`__new__()` if we want to be correct):

```
class numpy.ndarray(shape, dtype=float, ...)
```

So what `np.ndarray[foo, bar]` does is create a type for type hinting that means "a NumPy array of shape type `foo` and dtype `bar`". People normally don't call `np.ndarray()` directly anyway (rather using helpers such as `np.array()` or `np.full_like()` and the like), so this is doubly fine in NumPy.

Now, since most code runs with arrays of more than one possible number of dimensions, it would be a pain to have to specify an arbitrary number of lengths for the shape tuple (the first "argument" of `np.ndarray` as a generic type). I assume this was the motivation to define a type alias that is still a generic in the *second* "argument". This is `np.typing.NDArray`.

It lets you easily type hint something as an array of a given type without having to say anything about the shape, covering a vast subset of use cases (which would otherwise use `np.ndarray[typing.Any, ...]`). And this is still a generic, since you can parameterise it with a dtype. To quote [the docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.NDArray):

```
>>> print(npt.NDArray)
numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[+ScalarType]]

>>> print(npt.NDArray[np.float64])
numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.float64]]
```

As usual with generics, you're allowed to specify an argument to the generic type, but you're not required to. [`ScalarType`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bdec32181605c8179fd79624d14c1cf019de75af/numpy/_typing/_generic_alias.py#L238) is derived from `np.generic`, a base class that covers most (maybe all) NumPy scalar types. And the library code that defines `NDArray` is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bdec32181605c8179fd79624d14c1cf019de75af/numpy/_typing/_generic_alias.py#L240-L245), and is fairly transparent to the point of calling the helper `_GenericAlias` for older Python (a backport of [`typing.GenericAlias`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.GenericAlias)). What you have at the end is a type alias that is still generic in one variable.

---

To address the last part of your question:

> And why can I do `np.ndarray[float]`, ie just use one argument? What does that mean?

I think the anticlimactic explanation is that we again need to look at the signature of `np.ndarray()`:

```
class numpy.ndarray(shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0, strides=None, order=None)
```

There's one mandatory parameter (`shape`), all the others are optional. So I believe that `np.ndarray[float]` specifies that it corresponds to arrays whose shape is of type `float` (i.e. nonsense). There's [an explicit check to only allow 1 or 2 parameters in the generic type](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/291b301f109f82564083dccda4b11f3949759778/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L2838-L2847):

```c
    args_len = PyTuple_Check(args) ? PyTuple_Size(args) : 1;
    if ((args_len > 2) || (args_len == 0)) {
        return PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                            "Too %s arguments for %s",
                            args_len > 2 ? "many" : "few",
                            ((PyTypeObject *)cls)->tp_name);
    }
    generic_alias = Py_GenericAlias(cls, args);
```

This snippet checks that two arguments were passed to `__class_getitem__`, raises otherwise, and in the valid cases defers to [the C API version of `typing.GenericAlias`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typehints.html?highlight=py_genericalias#c.Py_GenericAlias).

I'm pretty sure that there's no *technical* reason to exclude the other parameters of the `ndarray` constructor from the generic type, but there was a semantic reason that the third parameter, `buffer` makes no sense to be included typing (or there was just a general push to reduce the generality of the generic type to most common use cases).

All that being said, I haven't been able to construct a small example in which a type passed for the `shape` of the generic type leads to type checking errors in `mypy`. From several attempts it seems as if the shape was always checked as if it were `typing.Any` rather than whatever was passed as the first parameter of `np.ndarray[...]`. For instance, consider the following example:

```py
import numpy as np

first: np.ndarray[tuple[int], np.dtype[np.int64]] = np.arange(3)  # OK

second: np.ndarray[tuple[int], np.dtype[np.int64]] = np.arange(3.0)  # error due to dtype mismatch

third: np.ndarray[tuple[int, int, int], np.dtype[np.int64]] = np.arange(3)  # no error even though shape mismatch
```

Running mypy 0.991 on Python 3.9 on this gives

```
foo.py:5: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "ndarray[Any, dtype[floating[Any]]]", variable has type "ndarray[Tuple[int], dtype[signedinteger[_64Bit]]]")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Only the dtype mismatch is found, but not the shape mismatch. And I see the same thing if I use `np.ndarray((3,), dtype=...)` instead of `np.arange()`, so it's not just due to weird typing of the `np.arange()` helper (although I used it as an example because this is one function that's guaranteed to return a 1d array). Since I can't explain this behaviour I can't be certain that my understanding is correct, but I have no better model.

To come back to a question you asked in a comment:

> Right, so then am I right in understanding that np.ndarray[int] is like np.ndarray[Any, int]?

No, at least we can exlude this (and what we see here is consistent with the first parameter only affecting the shape to whatever extent it does affect it):

```py
from typing import Any

import numpy as np

first: np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[np.int_]] = np.arange(3)  # OK because dtype matches

second: np.ndarray[np.dtype[np.int_]] = np.arange(3)  # OK because shape check doesn't actually work, and dtype is left as "any scalar"

third: np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[np.int_]] = np.arange(3.0)  # error due to dtype mismatch

fourth: np.ndarray[np.dtype[np.int_]] = np.arange(3.0)  # no error, so this can't be the same as the third option
```

The result from `mypy`:

```
foo.py:7: error: "ndarray" expects 2 type arguments, but 1 given  [type-arg]
foo.py:9: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "ndarray[Any, dtype[floating[Any]]]", variable has type "ndarray[Any, dtype[signedinteger[Any]]]")  [assignment]
foo.py:11: error: "ndarray" expects 2 type arguments, but 1 given  [type-arg]
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The four cases:

1. `first`: explicitly typed as "int array with any shape", no error on type correct assignment
2. `second`: typed as "array with an int-typed shape and any dtype", should fail because that's nonsense but doesn't (see the earlier musing about the impotence of shape type checks)
3. `third`: explicitly typed as another "int array with any shape", being assigned a *double* array, leading to an error
4. `fourth`: typed as "array with an int-typed shape and any dtype", leading to no error (see `second`). Since the third case leads to an error and the fourth doesn't, they can't be aliases of one another.

Also notable that mypy complains about the two lines where `np.ndarray[np.dtype[np.int_]]` is present:

> foo.py:7: error: "ndarray" expects 2 type arguments, but 1 given  [type-arg]

This sounds like a single-parameter use of the generic is forbidden as far as mypy is concerned. I'm not sure why this is the case, but this would certainly simplify the situation.

Comment: So in your `np.ndarray[foo, bar]` example, you say that `foo` is a "shape type"? Isn't a shape just a tuple of ints, ie `tuple[int, ...]`? (PS bounty awarded for effort and because its almost expired, even though I'm not sure about the answer yet)

Comment: @AlexanderSoare thanks. As I understand it, yes, it's the type of the first arg passed to `np.ndarray`. But here's the thing: `(2, 2)` is type `Tuple[int, int]` whereas `(2,)` is type `Tuple[int]`. These are different specific types. That being said I can't get mypy to fail in a quick test involving mismatching shapes so I'll have to look into this later. It's possible that numpy's API is too general to get accurate type hints on library function returns.

Comment: Right, so then am I right in understanding that `np.ndarray[int]` is like `np.ndarray[Any, int]`? If so, I suppose that under the hood there's an overload of sorts.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare sorry, I forgot about that part of your question. I'll look into it later and get back to you.

Comment: Nice one! Well, that single argument `np.ndarray` is still a bit of a mystery but I'm happy accepting that it's not supposed to take a single argument. I also tried: `np.ndarray[float, Any] == np.ndarray[float]` and `np.ndarray[Any, float] == np.ndarray[float]` and they both give `False`.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare according to NumPy it's supposed to take a single argument, they could've just forbidden that case along with the others. It's mypy (who often does stuff its own way) who thinks that the single-argument case is invalid. And the comparisons you mentioned are inconclusive, alas: `typing.List[typing.Any] == typing.List` is also `False` because formally these are different types (heck, even their own types are different). I don't know if there's a way to verify that two typing types fully correspond to one another. (I wouldn't be surprised if this wasn't possible in general cases.)